# Javascript Multi-level array of JSON objects - how to access key-value pair in second level or higher

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

Consider the following array of JSON objects:

```
myList = [
    {title:"Parent1",
        children:[{childname:"Child11"},
                     {childname:"Child12"}],
        cars:[{carname:"Car11"},
              {carname:"Car12"}]
    },
    {title:"Parent2",
        children:[{childname:"Child21"},
                     {childname:"Child22"}],
        cars:[{carname:"Car21"},
              {carname:"Car22"}]
    }
];
```

How does one access the "Child21" in javascript? The following options didn't work:

```
var myString = myList[1].children[0].childname; //Does not work
var myString = myList[1]["children"][0].childname; //Does not work
```

Comment: UGH*** Code formatting please!

Comment: Your first example `myList[1].children[0].childname` *does* work.

Comment: You mean carname... right crecentfresh...
Put that in an answer and I will vote for it

Comment: @Zoidberg: not sure, question is looking for `"Child21"` I think.

Comment: Your first option is correct; if it's not working on your set-up, the problem is not with your code (as written). "Children" is a bad choice, probably, for its's ubiquity of use; are you using any libraries that are interfering due to naming conventions?

Answer (score 9):

This worked OK for me:

```
myList[1].children[0].childname
```

This is also OK:

```
myList[1]["children"][0].childname;
```

In full,

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var myList = [
    {title:"Parent1",
        children:[{childname:"Child11"},
                     {childname:"Child12"}],
        cars:[{carname:"Car11"},
              {carname:"Car12"}]
    },
    {title:"Parent2",
        children:[{childname:"Child21"},
                     {childname:"Child22"}],
        cars:[{carname:"Car21"},
              {carname:"Car22"}]
    }
];
alert (myList[1].children[0].childname);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 to you and not the others because of the HTML example + 5 min earlier answer!

Answer (score 1):

var myString = myList[1].children[0].childname;

In FireFox's Firebug works

Answer (score 0):

This *does* work...

```
alert(myList[1].children[0].childname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first option...

```
var myString = myList[1].children[0].childname;
```

should work just fine.