# Multiple JSON Parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, blackberry-webworks

I have data in a JSON like this :

```
{
"output_type": "json",
"round_trip": false,
"search_queries": {
    "from": "AMQ",
    "to": "CGK",
    "date": "2013-01-03",
    "ret_date": "",
    "adult": 1,
    "child": 0,
    "infant": 0
},
"go_det": {
    "dep_airport": {
        "airport_code": "AMQ",
        "international": "0",
        "trans_name_id": "7564",
        "business_name": "PATTIMURA",
        "business_name_trans_id": "5923",
        "business_id": "20349",
        "country_name": "Indonesia ",
        "city_name": "Ambon",
        "province_name": "Maluku",
        "location_name": "Ambon"
    },
    "arr_airport": {
        "airport_code": "CGK",
        "international": "1",
        "trans_name_id": "7574",
        "business_name": "Soekarno-Hatta",
        "business_name_trans_id": "5935",
        "business_id": "20361",
        "country_name": "Indonesia ",
        "city_name": "Jakarta Barat",
        "province_name": "DKI Jakarta",
        "location_name": "Jakarta"
    },
    "date": "2013-01-03",
    "formatted_date": "03 Januari 2013"
},
"diagnostic": {
    "status": 200,
    "elapsetime": "1.9305",
    "memoryusage": "12.14MB",
    "confirm": "success",
    "lang": "id",
    "currency": "IDR"
},
"departures": {
    "result": [
        {
            "flight_id": "605783",
            "airlines_name": "BATAVIA",
            "flight_number": "Y6-852",
            "price_value": "1566900.00",
            "timestamp": "2012-10-25 08:51:48",
            "price_adult": "1566900.00",
            "price_child": "0.00",
            "price_infant": "0.00",
            "simple_departure_time": "06:55",
            "simple_arrival_time": "08:10",
            "stop": "Langsung",
            "long_via": "",
            "duration": "3 j 15 m",
            "image": "https://www.master18.tiket.com/images/icon_batavia.jpg"
        },
        {
            "flight_id": "605786",
            "airlines_name": "LION",
            "flight_number": "JT-1791",
            "price_value": "1391000.00",
            "timestamp": "2012-10-25 08:51:42",
            "price_adult": "1391000.00",
            "price_child": "0.00",
            "price_infant": "0.00",
            "simple_departure_time": "08:00",
            "simple_arrival_time": "10:35",
            "stop": "1 Transit",
            "long_via": "",
            "duration": "4 j 35 m",
            "image": "https://www.master18.tiket.com/images/icon_lion.jpg"
           }
       ]
    },
 }
```

I have tried a move like here :

[Sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886935/parsing-json-with-javascript)

[Sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650090/javascript-multi-level-array-of-json-objects-how-to-access-key-value-pair-in-s)

But have not found the results.

My code before like this :

```
var success = function(response) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < response.go_det.length; ++i ) {

      strKotaAwal   = response[i].go_det.dep_airport.airport_code;
      strKotaTujuan = response[i].go_det.arr_airport.airport_code;

  };
```

and i want to extract another data, ex :

```
[flight_id] => 605783
[airlines_name] => BATAVIA
[flight_number] => Y6-852
[price_value] => 1566900.00
[simple_departure_time] => 06:55
[simple_arrival_time] => 08:10
[duration] => 3 j 15 m
[image] => https://www.master18.tiket.com/images/icon_batavia.jpg
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I had written above...

var success = function(response) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < response.go_det.length; ++i ) {

      strKotaAwal   = response[i].go_det.dep_airport.airport_code;
      strKotaTujuan = response[i].go_det.arr_airport.airport_code;

  };

Comment: Shouldn't have the last comma in your json object   "}," should be "}"

Comment: Please put code inside your question, not in a comment, as it's better formatted there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ill elaborate rkm's answer a bit:

As long as the `response` is a javascript object amd not a JSON string you can use the `$.each()` method to iterate over the result. Otherwise use the `$.parseJSON()` method mentioned above.

```
$.each(response.go_det, function(i, val){
    console.log(val);
});
```

Since your response contains both object and string properties you might want to separate them, and also use some nested loops, in case you want to reach properties on each object "further down":

```
$.each(response.go_det, function(i, val){
    if(typeof(val) === 'string'){
        console.log(val);
    } else if (typeof(val) === 'object'){
         $.each(val, function(i2, val2){
             console.log(val2); //etc...
         });
    }
});
```

So, for example, if you want each flight_id you could do something like this:

```
$.each(object.departures.result, function(i, val){
    console.log(val.flight_id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use `parseJSON` method that takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.

Comment: The output of his JSON in his question already looks like JSON to me. No?