# How to parse multilevel json using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am very new to JSON, stuck in parsing multi level JSON array, I want to parse it using **javascript or jquery**. From the JSON I want to get `application id`, `application description` & `Product description`

```
[
    {
        "roadMapData": [
            {
                "applicationDetail": [
                    {
                        "applicationDescr": "R25updated-R25updated",
                        "applicationId": 352
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "productSubGrupDetail": [
                    {
                        "productGroupId": 271,
                        "productSubGroupDes": "TEST123-TEST1234"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "productSubGrupDetail": [
                    {
                        "productGroupId": 278,
                        "productSubGroupDes": "ggg-hhhh"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "roadMapData": [
            {
                "applicationDetail": [
                    {
                        "applicationDescr": "R25updated-R25updated",
                        "applicationId": 352
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "productSubGrupDetail": [
                    {
                        "productGroupId": 271,
                        "productSubGroupDes": "TEST123-TEST1234"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "productSubGrupDetail": [
                    {
                        "productGroupId": 278,
                        "productSubGroupDes": "ggg-hhhh1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [Javascript Multi-level array of JSON objects - how to access key-value pair in second level or higher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650090/javascript-multi-level-array-of-json-objects-how-to-access-key-value-pair-in-s) will help you

Comment: It won't works, can you please suggest something more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p4fbk/1/)**

Check [jQuery.parseJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

```
var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);
for (i = 0; i < jsonObj.length; i++) {
    var roadMapData = jsonObj[i].roadMapData;
    var applicationDetail = roadMapData[0].applicationDetail; //First Object
    var productSubGrupDetail1 = roadMapData[1].productSubGrupDetail; //Second Object
    var productSubGrupDetail2 = roadMapData[2].productSubGrupDetail; //Third Object
    console.log(applicationDetail[0].applicationDescr); //applicationDetail's First Object
    console.log(productSubGrupDetail1[0].productGroupId); //productSubGrupDetail1's First Object
    console.log(productSubGrupDetail2[0].productSubGroupDes); //productSubGrupDetail2's First Object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If data initially presented in JSON (as a string), you need first parse it into JavaScript object with `JSON.parse(json)`. Then you can access any property with object dot notation. If you are not familiar with objects in JavaScript, check [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).